# Where does this symbol lookup error come from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I ran `gem update`, and now certain rails commands return this error:

```
rails -v
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin/ruby: symbol lookup error: /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/etc-1.3.0/lib/etc.so: undefined symbol: rb_deprecate_constant
```

The exact same error is returned for `rails assets:precompile`, `gem install` etc.

Using rbenv, with ruby 2.6.3:

```
rbenv which ruby
/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/bin/ruby
```

My rails server is still running, but I'm not sure it'll survive a reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Rockwell Rice, I believe the gem name is `etc`. However, running `bundle open etc` yields: `Could not find gem 'etc'.` unfortunately.

Comment: https://github.com/ruby/etc/issues/12

Comment: The issue is in the C code of the shared library. It _looks_ like 1.3 includes the purported fix (although 1.3 is still behind). It can also be due to an MRI version mis-match. If you cannot upgrade your Ruby, next try the current version of etc. If you can't move that far ahead on etc, revert the etc bump.

Comment: @DaveNewton 1.4 has not been pushed to Rubygems.org yet. So you either need to setup your gemfile to get it from github, host it yourself or downgrade.

Comment: Looking at [this changeset](https://github.com/ruby/etc/compare/v1.2.0...v1.3.0), it appears the above issue was [fixed](https://github.com/ruby/etc/commit/7cbf03d22d74f50ab3a488d2c52fcd4901355466) in `etc v1.3.0`. So I'm surprised this error still appears present on your setup.

Comment: Thanks for the insights Dave Newton, max and Tom Lord. I'm getting a sense of the issue. Trying to check which version of the `etc` gem that I have installed, by running `gem list` but unfortunately, that also produces the above error, with no other output. It's very strange that the server is still live. I'll try upgrading the ruby version in dev (using rbenv), and then try to do the same in production.